Ad-invariance implies ad-invariance
While reading these notes, I've come across the following statement (beginning of chapter 3, p.9) concerning a symmetric bilinear form $\langle ~,~\rangle:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of a Lie group $G$:
"Recall that Ad-invariance means $\langle\text{Ad}_g a,\text{Ad}_g b\rangle = \langle a,b\rangle$ for all $g\in G$ (and all $a,b\in\mathfrak{g}$), and that it implies the ad-invariance $\langle[c,a],b\rangle = -\langle a,[c,b]\rangle$ for all $c\in\mathfrak{g}$."
I don't see why this statement holds — why does Ad invariance imply ad-invariance? Is it trivial? Could you please refer to me any good reference on this topic that explains why this holds, or when (for which Lie groups $G$) is this true?

Isn’t ad the derivative of Ad at the identity?

@TedShifrin yes I tried to reason along those line but couldn't figure it out... is your comment along the lines of Kato's reply below?

Write $\text{ad}ca  = \frac d{dt}|{t=0} \text{Ad}{\exp(tc)}a$ and differentiate $\langle \text{Ad}{\exp(tc)}a, \text{Ad}_{\exp(tc)}b\rangle = \text{const.}$.

The point is that $\mathrm{ad}_X = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}$. So by Ad-invariance we have:
$$ \left\langle\mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Y, \mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Z\right\rangle = \langle Y, Z\rangle.$$
Differentiating both sides at $t=0$ yields:
\begin{align} 0 &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \left\langle\mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Y, \mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Z\right\rangle \\
&=  \left\langle \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Y, Z\right\rangle + \left\langle Y, \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\mathrm{Ad}
_{\exp(tX)}Z\right\rangle \\
&=\left\langle \mathrm{ad}_X Y, Z\right\rangle + \left\langle Y, \mathrm{ad}_X Z\right\rangle \\
& = \left\langle [X,Y], Z\right\rangle + \left\langle Y, [X,Z]\right\rangle
\end{align}
This is simply using product rule.

Let $g=e^{t c} \in G$ for some $c\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $t$ is a (small) parameter. Then you obtain
$$
\mathrm{Ad}_{g}(a) = e^{tc} \, a \, e^{-tc} = a + t[c,a] +\frac{1}{2}t^{2}[c,[c,a]] +\cdots
$$
and a similar expansion for $\mathrm{Ad}_{g}(b)$. Then
$$
\langle\mathrm{Ad}_{g}(a), \mathrm{Ad}_{g}(b) \rangle 
= \langle a, b \rangle + t 
\left(
\langle [c,a], b \rangle +
\langle a, [c, b] \rangle 
\right)
+ O(t^2)
$$
Compaing this with  $\langle a, b \rangle $ gives the desired result.

Thank you for your answer. Do you have any reference where the expansion you use in the first equality, in terms of powers of $t$, is proven for an arbitrary Lie group? I have encountered this result for matrix Lie groups (though unproven) in my Quantum Mechanics lectures, by the name of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Since any Lie group can be embedded into a (sufficiently large) matrix Lie group, so it is enough to prove for matrix Lie groups.  You may also find it useful to read the texts around the page 116 of Warner "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups" (GTM 94, Springer).

@ÉGG This is not the BCH formula (that is about finding $Z$ such that $\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\exp(Z)$) but it is a basic fact that is true for all Lie groups. As Ted Shifrin points out in his comments this is all unnecessary, however, as we can just differentiate.
